# connecting exchange server EMS from powershell remoting via HTTPS

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-remoting, winrm, exchange-management-shell

I'm trying to resolve an issue we are facing.

we are able to communicate to Exchange Server EMS Script from remote machine through winRM HTTP authentication.

```
$newSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://test.domain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credentials    
Import-PSSession $newSession
```

But we have to impose WinRM HTTPS, so I have set everything required for that including certificate creation , winRM settings etc.

And we are able to connect to remote machine where exchange server is available:

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName test.domain.com -Credential $credentials -UseSSL

and this works.

Now when I'm using -UseSSL in New-PSSession/Enter-PSSession for EMS, its not working:

```
$newSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://test.domain.com/PowerShell/ -Credential $Credentials -UseSSL
```

> Error: New-PSSession : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the
>   specified named parameters.

**Please note: I need WinRM (powershell) Connectivity through HTTPS: -UseSSL Authentication. Not with Kerberos/Defaut/CredSSP**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at parameter sets in the documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849717.aspx eg when you using URI eg

> Parameter Set: Uri
>   New-PSSession [-ConnectionUri]  [-AllowRedirection] [-Authentication  {Default | Basic | Negotiate | NegotiateWithImplicitCredential | Credssp | Digest | Kerberos} ] [-CertificateThumbprint  ] [-ConfigurationName  ] [-Credential  ] [-EnableNetworkAccess] [-Name  ] [-SessionOption  ] [-ThrottleLimit  ] [ ]

What you should be doing is specify the https prefix instead of using the -useSSL switch which will ensure that connection is over https ("https://test.domain.com/PowerShell/);. The -useSSL is meant to be used when you using the -ComputerName parameter.